# unable to send post request on the server using backbone.js

Tags: node.js, backbone.js

I am making post request on the server with an id the request looks like this:

```
 app.post('campaign/update/:_id', campaign.update);
```

the save method is this which calls post request:

```
 this.model.save(null, {success: function(data){
            });
        }});
```

and the model is:

```
var CampaignEditModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    urlRoot:"http://localhost:3033/campaign/update/",
     url : function(){
     var url = this.urlRoot + this.id;
      console.log("in model:"+ this.id ) ;
      return url;
  },
    idAttribute: "_id",
    defaults:{
        "id":"",
        "Name" :""
    }
});
```

the request goes like this:

```
 http://localhost:3033/campaign/update/5c72e198-c8fd-11e2-9cfa-74867a028324
```

the problem is the console shows the error:

```
 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```